# Find the lowest number without comparing

Tags: actionscript-3

My problem is just really simple,
I found somethng in the stackoverflow a same problem but it finds the largest number between 2 numbers

```
var c =(Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b - 2*a*b ) + a + b) / 2;
```

can somebody help me revised this equation so the lowest number should print out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i have one solution

```
c = ((a + b) - sqrt((a - b) * (a - b))) / 2
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code as below:

```
var c =((a + b) - Math.sqrt((a - b) * (a - b))) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

```
c = ((a + b) - sqrt((a - b) * (a - b))) / 2
```

equals

```
c = ((a + b) - (a - b)) / 2
```

equals

```
c = (a - a + b + b) /2 = b
```

or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Math class for it? Like `Math.min(a,b)` ????